# How to show data in html table using PHP

Tags: html

This is my code the table appears up with the header and everything but the row with the td tag data shows nothing at all

```
echo "<p></p>";
//display name of the page and some random text
echo "<h2>".$pagename."</h2>";

if($_POST['h_prodid'] > 0){ 
    $newprodid = $_POST['h_prodid'];
    $reququantity =$_POST['quantity'];
    $_SESSION['basket'][$newprodid]=$reququantity;
    echo "<p>Your basket has been updated</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Existing basket</p>";
}

echo "<table border = '1'>
        <tr><th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>";
echo "<td>".$reququantity."</td>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: what does html source reveal... code?

Comment: does `$_POST['quantity']` even have value?

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean

Comment: You need to wrap your `<td>` in a `<tr></tr>`, among other things. Here's some basics about HTML tables: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: did you start the session and does the session array have value?

Comment: you have 3 `th`'s but one `<td>` - this is failing on too many levels

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I did that but it did not work

Comment: More important there are no `<tr>` ... `</tr>` tags around the `<td></td>` tags

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are more errors in your code/syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes it has values which is from my database and I only started with one td to show if the data appears

Comment: @MagnusEriksson echo "<tr><td>".$reququantity."</tr></td>";  is this how to do it

Comment: Tables are only guaranteed to work properly if you code than properly. Each ROW ('<tr>`) need to have the same number of columns

Comment: look at your html source, what does it reveal? ;-)

Comment: No, that's not correct. Please read the page I linked to. You need to learn the basics about HTML tables. Also, you have an answer below with the correct syntax.

Comment: **Do a search on** _Basic HTML tables syntax rules_. SO is not a tutorial site

Answer (score 2):

The reason your data is NOT displaying in the html is because it is NOT in a `tr` ( table row ) - simply a floating table cell

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

    echo "<h2>".$pagename."</h2>";

    if( isset( $_POST['h_prodid'],$_POST['quantity'] ) ){

        if( $_POST['h_prodid'] > 0 ){ 

            $newprodid = $_POST['h_prodid'];
            $reququantity =$_POST['quantity'];
            $_SESSION['basket'][$newprodid]=$reququantity;


            echo "<p>Your basket has been updated</p>";
        }else{
            echo "<p>Existing basket</p>";
        }



        echo "
            <table border = '1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>{$reququantity}</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be nicer to the OP to put 3 blank cells in the right place in that table.

Comment: Then there is something else seriously wrong that you are not sharing with us

Comment: @Riggs it works now only problem is how would I make the quantity come up as the values does not show up

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['quantity']` has a value in it? Are you sure the field on the form has a `name="quantity"` attribute

Comment: Good point @RiggsFolly, I should have done just that - thanks for your input / edit